Serving images from device cache (web app)
I have a go / htmx stack app that is serving images from s3 with a cloudfront distribution in front. I am attempting to load images from a service worker and store them in a cache then serve them from the cache if they exist there before sending an actual network request to cloudfront. The images are requested via an img src tag via the application code. The service worker currently is successful in storing these images in the cache, but the screenshot here is confusing as it's leading me to believe that the image is being requested from cloudfront again.

I am unable to log any response from the following service worker code. I am only pasting the "fetch" listener code of the service worker as it is the relevant code:
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.destination === 'image' && event.request.url.includes("cloudfront.net")) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(response => {
          // Return the cached image if available, otherwise fetch from network
          console.log(response)
          return response || fetch(event.request).then(networkResponse => {
            // Cache the new image and return it
            const responseClone = networkResponse.clone();
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
              cache.put(event.request, responseClone);
            });
            return networkResponse;

          });
        }).catch((err) => {
          // Fallback image if network fetch fails and not in cache
          console.log("not in: ", err)
          return;
        })
    );
  }
});

I would expect to see (disk cache) or (memory cache) next to the images fetched by the service worker.

browser caching is a solved problem.  I'm not clear on why you feel the need to reinvent it.

Why is my browser downloading the files every time they are requested? What do sizes of the files shown in the screenshot represent? Prior to implementing this code, the browser is showing files sizes every time they are requested.

to enable caching on cloudfront you can add relevant headers to your s3 stuff, then the browser will handle the rest.

Caching responses to s3 is working fine. I mostly get "hits" from cloudfront according to the network requests. Is it expected to see file sizes from the same requests to cloudfront? If images are being pulled from the browser cache, why is there any content being downloaded?

cloudfront can cache origin's responses, and your browser can cache cloudfront's responses.  If it's working, you should see 304s and investigating in the browser should show "from disk cache" or something similar.

That's exactly the problem. I am not seeing any signs of successful cached cloud front responses :(

So the problem is that I am generating a signed URL for each image every page refresh so that is sending a new request every time the page is reloaded.
